# How do I expose a Maven2 repo as a Maven1 repo in Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

We have a Maven1 project that needs artifacts from a standard Maven2 (remote) repo and I would like to resolve this by using our central Artifactory.

Currently I'm running a local Artifactory 3.0.3 OSS, standalone, with default settings (only added my virtual repo).

I have created a virtual repository that only referes to a single maven2 remote repo (`spring-release`) and uses `maven-1-default` in `Repository Layout` (`Advanced Settings` tab).
I've added a dependency to my `project.xml`:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.aws</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-aws-maven</artifactId>  
    <version>1.2.2</version>  
    <type>jar</type>  
</dependency>
```

But Maven can not resolve this dependency when I run "maven build".

Is it possible to have a m2 -> m1 "bridge" in Artifactory 3.0.3 OSS or do I need the Pro add-on?

//Joran

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Define a new [virtual repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories), add the Maven2 repositories you want to convert, select `maven-1-default` in `Repository Layout` dropbox in `Advanced` tab. Done.
Now resolve the artifacts from the new virtual repository and you're all set.

Comment: thanks for the reply @JBaruch, I thought that would be the solution but I can not get that to work. I get an `!` in `Resolved Repository` for every pre-defined m2-repository I try to use and no dependency from these repositories can be resolved by Maven1